# error TS5083: Cannot read file 'tsconfig.json' when building app via Docker?

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here as I know the tsconfig file exists at the place that the app is looking for it but, when running a Dockerfile, my build fails complaining about not being able to read the tsconfig file? I have an `.eslintrc` file that specifies the location of tsconfig, and have verified that both `.eslintrc` and `tsconfig.json` are present in my docker build, but for some reason it seems unable to find tsconfig even though it prints the exact location of where the file should be?

```
#12 [stage-0 8/8] RUN npm run build
#12 0.303 
#12 0.303 > digittron@1.0.0 build
#12 0.303 > tsc -b src
#12 0.303 
#12 0.390 error TS5083: Cannot read file '/opt/node_app/src/tsconfig.json'.
#12 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c npm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-slim

RUN npm i npm@latest -g

USER node

WORKDIR /opt/node_app

COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./
# Setup npmrc
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=TOKEN \
    TOKEN=<placeholder> && \
    echo //npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${TOKEN} >> ~/.npmrc && \
    echo @${OWNER}:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/ >> ~/.npmrc && \
    npm ci && npm cache clean --force
ENV PATH /opt/node_app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

WORKDIR /opt/node_app/app
COPY --chown=node:node src/ src/
RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Directory listing

```
├── Dockerfile
├── src
│   ├── bot.ts
│   ├── client.ts
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── client
│   │   │   ├── EventSubClient.ts
│   │   │   └── Logger.ts
│   │   ├── commands
│   │   │   └── commandHandler.ts
│   │   ├── permissions
│   │   │   └── permissions.ts
│   │   ├── structures
│   │   │   ├── Command.ts
│   │   │   ├── CommandCache.ts
│   │   │   ├── CustomRewardsCache.ts
│   │   │   └── Scheduler.ts
│   │   ├── utils
│   │   │   └── SongRequest.ts
│   │   └── utils.ts
│   └── tsconfig.json
```

The only reason I could think of this error appearing is due to me installing node modules in a different directory to the actual project source in my Dockerfile? And if that's a problem, how would I resolve it (aside from moving everything to the same directory)?

Comment: You have to be in the src directory as your working directory

Comment: That doesn't seem right - I've set my working directory to a parent directory before, copied over a src directory and built just fine, removing the `WORKDIR /opt/node_app/app` gets everything running smoothly. Even stranger, replacing `COPY --chown=node:node src/ src/` with `COPY --chown=node:node . .` gets everything working as well, so maybe I'm missing some parent file somewhere?

Comment: The `WORKDIR` changes into a subdirectory before you `COPY` the `src` directory in; you probably have a `/opt/node_app/app/src/tsconfig.json`, where the error message suggests it's not expecting the `app` subdirectory.

Comment: But I'm directly copying `src/` to `src/` the only `/app` directory mentioned is in the WORKDIR argument. My project tree is listed above and there's no `/app` mentioned anywhere, unless I'm misunderstanding you?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is just a problem with paths specified in `Dockerfile` and `tsc` configuration.

I don't have all of the details of your project, so created a minimal project to replicate the issue. The initial version of the simplified project did have the same error as you observed. That's fixed in the details below.

Try this simple working project. Once you have this working you can layer back your original code. Simplified project structure (no need for change from your project structure but you will need the `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files.)

```
├── Dockerfile
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
└── src
    ├── bot.ts
    └── tsconfig.json
```

`Dockerfile` (Keep things simple with the `npm` configuration.)

```
FROM node:lts-slim

RUN npm i npm@latest -g

WORKDIR /opt/node_app

COPY package*.json .

RUN npm ci
ENV PATH /opt/node_app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY --chown=node:node src/ src/

RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

`package.json` (The path in the `start` command is related to the setting of `outDir` in `tsconfig.js`.)

```
{
  "name": "landing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "",
    "build": "tsc -b src",
    "start": "node src/dist/bot.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "5.4.2"
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.js`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "rootDir": ".",
      "strict": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "module": "commonjs",
      "target": "ES6"
    },
    "include": ["./**/*"]
  }
```

`bot.ts` (Do something! See `package.json` where the start rule specifies that this file should be run. You'll most likely want to change this too!)

```
console.log("Hello World!");
```

[image]

Comment: why install node again (`npm i npm@latest -g`) when its being provided by container itself `node:lts-slim`.

Comment: I often got an alert that the node version I was using was out of date, so I decided to just update it manually